# How to merge specific commits into a protected branch?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I have a repository on Github and try to follow the Gitflow workflow. I have a protected `main` and `dev` branch.

The `dev` branch is 2 commits ahead of the `main` branch. I want to cherry-pick one commit from the `dev` branch to the `main` branch.

AFAIK Github does not provide a "cherry-pick into PR" feature. So when trying to create a PR from `dev` into `main` it always tries to merge both commits into `main`.

I cloned the repository locally, checked out `main` and ran `git cherry-pick {commitId}`. Now `main` contains the work from the specific commit in the `dev` branch but I'm not able to push it since this branch is protected.

What is the correct way to merge specific commits into a protected `main` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario, I would create another branch from `main` and cherry-pick the specific commit from `dev` into it.

You should then be able to create a Pull Request from your new branch into `main`, and follow the approval process to get the commit merged into `main`.

Comment: This. And In Gitflow it would be called a hotfix branch.

Comment: was hoping for a simpler solution but thanks, that helped :)

Comment: This creates a new commit hash, so main and dev will have different histories